# Change URL of single WebViewActivity by clicking each button on another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

> I'm beginner in android development, i need help. I have two
>   activities, MainActivity contain 3 Buttons(Google, Facebook, Twitter),
>   WebViewActivity contain webview, how to change URL in WebViewActivity
>   on each button click?
>
> For example if i click on Google Button it will move to
>   WebViewActivity and the url "goole.com" should be open in same
>   WebViewActivity
>
> if i click on Facebook Button it will move to same WebViewActivity and
>   the url "facebook.com" should be open in same WebViewActivity
>
> if i click on Twitter Button it will move to same WebViewActivity and
>   the url "twitter.com" should be open in same WebViewActivity.

Please tell me according to my code.My Code is:

> MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void LoadThisUrl(View view) {
    if(view==findViewById(R.id.Google)){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if(view==findViewById(R.id.Facebook)){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    if(view==findViewById(R.id.Twitter)){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Google"
        android:id="@+id/Google"
        android:onClick="LoadThisUrl"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Facebook"
        android:id="@+id/Facebook"
        android:onClick="LoadThisUrl"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Twitter"
        android:id="@+id/Twitter"
        android:onClick="LoadThisUrl"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> WebViewActivity.java

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http:\\www.atifsoftwares.blogspot.com");
    }
}
```

> activity_webview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.WebViewActivity">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView">
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it my self, adding Bundle to each button.

> Now in MainActivity.java

```
public void LoadThisUrl(View view) {
        if(view==findViewById(R.id.Google)){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Url", "http://google.com");
            startActivity(i);
        }
        if(view==findViewById(R.id.Facebook)){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Url", "http://facebook.com");
            startActivity(i);
        }
        if(view==findViewById(R.id.Twitter)){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("Url", "http://twitter.com");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
```

> WebViewActivity.java

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        //webView.loadUrl("http:\\www.atifsoftwares.blogspot.com");
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String url = b.getCharSequence("Url").toString();
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```